# How do I separate the bars in the bar graph and also make tickmarks for all items in sorted(bookp)?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

[Current bar graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvvN6.png)

I'm using Google Colab for my project and I would like to make a bar for each item in sorted(bookp). I.e. a bar for 4.7 with space between the bar for 4.8.

Answer (score 0):

The width of the bar graph is automatically scaled, so you need to specify the axis. So setting the x-axis index and the display label will create the intended graph.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

bookp=[4.8,4.7,4.6,4.5,4.9,4.4,4.3,4.0,4.2,4.1,3.9,3.8,3.6,3.3]
booknum=[1,1,2,3,14,6,8,25,38,60,105,108,127,52]

label = [str(x) for x in sorted(bookp)]
width = 0.6
idx = np.arange(len(label))

plt.bar(idx, booknum, width, edgecolor='black', color='c', align='center') 
plt.xlabel("Movie Ratings")
plt.ylabel("Number of Movies")
plt.title('Amazon Best Selling Books Ratings')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.xticks(idx, label)
 
plt.show()
```

[image]